# groovy.sql.Sql Springboot cli

Tags: groovy, spring-boot

I'm attempting to create a small Springboot application that uses the groovy.sql.Sql class to connect to an Oracle database(the Oracle jar has already been grabbed and is in the spring boot classpath). This is a very simple example for proof of concept/testing.

```
import groovy.sql.Sql

@RestController 
class ThisWillActuallyRun {

   @RequestMapping("/")
   String home() {
     oracleSql = Sql.newInstance(jdbc:oracle:thin:@oracle-db:1521:db-name,
                                "oracle-user",
                                "oracle-pass",
                                "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver")

     row = oracleSql.firstRow("select foo from blah")
     return "ok"
   }
}
```

When the application is ran using the command:

```
spring run test_for_so.groovy
```

The following error is produced:

```
startup failed:
file:test_for_so.groovy: 1: unable to resolve class groovy.sql.Sql  @ line 1, column 1.
   import groovy.sql.Sql
```

Answer (score 2):

What groovy jars are you including as dependencies?  The `groovy` jar only includes the base language support.  Change it to `groovy-all` to get the full language and library package.  For example, in gradle, use:

```
dependencies {
    compile "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all"
    ...
}
```

In maven, it would look like this:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

You can also just add the `groovy-sql` on top of the `groovy` package if you don't want everything.

Comment: For this app, I'm not using a POM file, the code listed above and how to run it is all that there is. This was a small simple app. Concerning your comment about the groovy jar only includes the base language support, is that true for when you invoke groovy from the command line too?

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem. I just found the solution.
Add below code.

```
@Grab('groovy-sql')
```

After groovy-sql you can use

```
import groovy.sql.Sql
```